# Jquery toggle show/hide fields

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to offer a toggle show/hide for some fields that are not mandatory. Is there is a modules for this or would it be a case of using a template and jquery.

Comment: jQuery will well for this:

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select1').change(function() {
      switch ($(this).val()) {
        case '1':
          $('#field2').hide();
          break;
        default:
          $('#field2').show();
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}) (jQuery);
You can also try Conditional Field module but it is in development.

Comment: why you put shyghar answer as accepted answer? his answer  have not any mention of jquery.

Comment: the person who added the jquery answer, did it whilst I was reading the other answers, and then deleted it after I marked the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the not mandatory field in a group installing [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group). 
The group have a 'collapsible' option.

Answer (score 1):

You can Put your fields toghether with [Field Group Module](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) ,and after it you can show/hide it(field groups) by custom jquery code.